# Create Files Automatically using PHP script

Tags: php, html, forms, fwrite

I have a project that needs to create files using the fwrite in php. What I want to do is to make it generic, I want to make each file unique and dont overwrite on the others. 
I am creating a project that will record the text from a php form and save it as html, so I want to output to have generated-file1.html and generated-file2.html, etc.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a count of the number of html files in a given directory

```
 $filecount = count(glob("/Path/to/your/files/*.html"));
```

and then your new filename will be something like:

```
$generated_file_name = "generated-file".($filecount+1).".html";
```

and then fwrite using `$generated_file_name`

Although I've had to do a similar thing recently and used uniq instead. Like this:

```
$generated_file_name = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).".html";
```

Comment: Good answer - does exactly what the OP asks for, and also provides an alternate option.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the time as the first part of the filename (as that should then result in files being listed in chronological/alphabetic order, and then borrow from @TomcatExodus to improve the chances of the filename being unique (incase of two submissions being simultaneous).

```
<?php
$data = $_POST;
$md5  = md5( $data );
$time = time();
$filename_prefix = 'generated_file';
$filename_extn   = 'htm';

$filename = $filename_prefix.'-'.$time.'-'.$md5.'.'.$filename_extn;

if( file_exists( $filename ) ){
 # EXTREMELY UNLIKELY, unless two forms with the same content and at the same time are submitted
  $filename = $filename_prefix.'-'.$time.'-'.$md5.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$filename_extn;
 # IMPROBABLE that this will clash now...
}

if( file_exists( $filename ) ){
 # Handle the Error Condition
}else{
  file_put_contents( $filename , 'Whatever the File Content Should Be...' );
}
```

This would produce filenames like:

- generated_file-1300080525-46ea0d5b246d2841744c26f72a86fc29.htm
- generated_file-1300092315-5d350416626ab6bd2868aa84fe10f70c.htm
- generated_file-1300109456-77eae508ae79df1ba5e2b2ada645e2ee.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make absolutely sure that you will not overwrite an existing file you could append a [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to the filename. If you want it to be sequential you'll have to read existing files from your filesystem and calculate the next increment which can result in an IO overhead.

I'd go with the uniqid() method :)

Comment: Just a quick interjection - if they wanted the filenames to be sequential (although not using a incrementing counter), you could use `time()` to return the Unix time (which should be sequential) and then append `uniqid()` to improve the chances of avoiding a collision.

Answer (score 0):

If your implementation should result in unique form results every time (therefore unique files) you could hash form data into a filename, giving you unique paths, as well as the opportunity to quickly sort out duplicates;

```
// capture all posted form data into an array
// validate and sanitize as necessary
$data = $_POST;

// hash data for filename
$fname = md5(serialize($data));

$fpath = 'path/to/dir/' . $fname . '.html';

if(!file_exists($fpath)){

    //write data to $fpath

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this:

```
$i = 0;  
while (file_exists("file-".$i.".html")) {  
 $i++;  
}
$file = fopen("file-".$i.".html");
```

Comment: Whilst this would, indeed, work, it could take a long time to find the next number available. For instance, if the form is submitted 1,000 times, this code would perform the `while()` loop 1,000 times before it found the next available number. @Emmanuel's solution would be faster - it looks for how many files with names matching a specified pattern exist, then adds 1 to that count. Same result, but certainly faster in the long run.